# Question about Microsoft robotics developer studio sample code

Tags: c#, .net

If anyone has come across the the Arcos sample code in the MRDS can you please let me know what the following code fragment does in the ArcosDrive.cs file. I am more interested in the lines "arcos.Update update  = new arcos.Update(raw);" and "_arcosPort.Post(update);".

Thanks.

```
void VelocityHandler(Velocity velocity)
{
    arcos.RawType raw = new arcos.RawType();

    raw.Command = "Vel";
    raw.Integer = (short)velocity.Body.Velocity;
    raw.Flags = arcos.RawFlags.Integer;

    arcos.Update update  = new arcos.Update(raw);
    _arcosPort.Post(update);

    Activate(Arbiter.Choice(update.ResponsePort,
            delegate(DefaultUpdateResponseType response)
            {
                velocity.ResponsePort.Post(DefaultSubmitResponseType.Instance);
            },
            delegate(Fault fault)
            {
                velocity.ResponsePort.Post(fault);
            })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a deep breath and careful thinking :P I managed to figure it out.

Seems that a PostUnknownType is like an automatic type casting whereby the type that is posted is recognized automatically without having to define multiple post types.

In the case of RawType, a RawType post eventually triggers a call to RawCommandHandler defined in the ArcosState class.

Hope someone finds this useful.